# set up a web page on github pages, but Chrome/Edge can not get the updated page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I put a index.html on github page.
Firefox can get the newest web page after the update.
But if I use Chrome/Edge to access the web page, it always return the non-updated page.
I try to disable the cache in Chrome and Edge, same result.

Is there anyone met the same problem?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before. You can try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to reload the page while ignoring cached content.